# Why doesn't JQuery UI autocomplete style minus (-) signs correctly in options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

## Setup

I am using jquery-ui for an autocomplete list. It pops up the options on focus. I don't decide on the options. Some are user configured from the database some are set by 3rd party standards. I am using jquery 1.11.1 and jquery-ui 1.11.1. I am using chrome for pc (windows 8.1) and mac. The versions/os/browser do not seem to make a difference. I am using the default jquery style sheets.

## The Problem

One of the pre-specified options list only contains a plus (+) and minus (-) sign. I would love to change these to text like 'positive' and 'negative' but that is not an option. The minus (-) sign does not format correctly. It always appears as a blank row in the options list. In the image below the two blank lines are minus (-) signs.

[image]

## The Code

It's very simple and easy to reproduce. I have a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jorgbw7a/).

Basically a textfield type input with the js code:

```
var $input = $('input');
$input.autocomplete(
{
  source: ['+', '-', '-', '+'],
  minLength: 0
});

$input.autocomplete('search', '');
```

## The Solution

It seems the minus (-) symbol is some sort of flagged character that creates a divider in the list. This seems useful in other use cases but for me it breaks everything. I tried to do a `encodeURIComponent` but of course that had no effect. I do not want to override any js or jquery-ui css to display this character as it may break other behaviors on the site should I legitimately need a divider.

## The Question

How do I tell jquery-ui autocomplete to display this minus (-) sign as a normal option?

## Update 1

It appears the autocomplete actually uses the ui.menu._isDivider function to determine if the value is a divider. I hacked jqueryui to confirm this. Obviously hacking the library is not ideal. Is their a way to overwrite the menu ui function before attaching the autocomplete maybe? Perhaps a function that can edit a widgets initialization script?

Comment: The issue is because jQueryUI use the `-` as a key for inserting a divider into the dropdown. There is no way around this. You can't even use a character entity (such as `&ndash;`) instead of the `-` as jQuery uses `text()` to populate the items. You're probably best to use another autocomplete library instead of hacking around this short-sightedness. It's another reason jQueryUI isn't very good.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have used jquery for years and it's kind of ignorant to just randomly say "It's not very good" because of one oversight. Oversite aside it's lean, flexible, powerful, performant, and comprehensive. Leave helpful comments here and bash jquery-ui in your opinion blog.

Comment: It's not random - there's lots of issues like this in jQueryUI. I also took the time to diagnose your problem, so you're welcome for that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I already identified that issue in my question. Thanks for reading but "just don't use that really powerful library" isn't a helpful comment.

Comment: Fair point. I shall leave you looking for a solution and wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Maybe raise this as a bug report in the official site?

Comment: @TJ That's a good idea. It seems Rory was correct. I have not found a solution as of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the OP already has many of the details figured out in the updates to the question, as well as in [their own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37816024/4376460), I've found what I think is a more controlled way to solve the issue.

As the OP figured out, the problem is that the [autocomplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), creates a [menu widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/), and as per the spec for the default implementation of the menu's [`_isDivider` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-_isDivider):

> By default any item that contains just spaces and/or dashes is considered a divider.

However, jQuery UI offers a nice way to solve this, by giving access to all necessary components.  An example solution would be:

```js
$('#some-selector').autocomplete('widget').menu('instance')._isDivider = function () {
    return false;
};
```

The [`.autocomplete('widget')`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-widget) section gets the menu *element* associated with the autocomplete element.  The [`.menu('instance')`](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-instance) section gets the menu *instance*, which is the object that was returned when the menu was created.  From there, you can override the `_isDivider` method however you like.

Comment: As this is an instance specific override I think this is a better solution. Now marked as the accepted answer in place of my own.

Answer (score 2):

## Answering my own question.

Got it!!!!

So I found the `menu._isDivider` function is used to define the divider in autocomplete. As autocomplete creates an instance of menu to store it's values.

I tried to overwrite the `_isDivider` function for the autocomplete instance but it appears that after initialization is too late for the initial search. Perhaps I could add the values after update instead but I haven't tried that.

So I had to find a way to overwrite the function before initialization. And here it is:

```
jQuery.ui.menu.prototype._isDivider = function(){return false}
```

Working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jorgbw7a/2/).

Of course you can replace this with any regex or other type of search to set other specific values to be dividers instead.

Directly from jquery-ui (match spaces or dashes):

```
return !/[^\-\u2014\u2013\s]/.test( item.text() );
```

Of course this solution will affect all jquery-ui elements after it is set. So beware.